# Probability book choosing questions

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

So I am doing homework and have the following question

If 3 books are picked at random from a shelf containing 5 novels, 3 books of poems, and a dictionary. What is the probability that

(a) the dictionary is selected

(b) 2 novels and 1 book of poems are selected

for "a" I got $$\frac{\binom{9}{1}}{\binom{9}{3}}=\frac{9}{84}$$

for "b" $$\frac{\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{1}}{\binom{9}{3}}=\frac{30}{84}$$

Are these answers correct?

Comment: The answer to b) is wrong. You are picking two books among the 3 poems so should be $ 3 \choose 2$ and you should change the denominator accordingly

Comment: Whoops typed it wrong, updated

Comment: it doesn't show to me that you have updated it correctly

Comment: I changed the number of books it was looking for, it needed 2 novels and 1 books of poems

Answer (score 6):

a) is wrong since there is only one dictionary to pick, and the rest of the two books can be picked from the other 8 books:$$\frac{\binom{1}{1}\binom{8}{2}}{\binom{9}{3}}$$
b) is correct.